# getting process ID of a pub serve to then kill that thread/process

Tags: dart, dart-pub

So when I run my Polymer Dart application, i use `pub serve` and the serve is created and served.  It will stay running until until i break out of it.  I was curious if there is a way to programmatically stop it.

One of the options I was looking at was looking at the running processes and then killing the pub serve process.

I was not sure though how i would get the process id to kill it, or unless there was another option.

Maybe someone has an even better approach to shutdown pub serve on the machine automatically, as a form of cleanup?

The issue I have noticed is that if i get the running proceesses, i only see "cmd" as a process so that isnt the best determining factor.

I was not sure if there was a way via pub on serve to get its process if, if it set a flag or global of sorts I could leverage

Comment: What do you mean by 'shutdown pub serve on the machine automatically'?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus after i do `pub serve` and im done, i just break out of it.  if i wanted to spool up that process and detach it from the console, how would i fetch and kill the pub serve thread?    example:  `pub serve &` to call it detached from the terminal / cmd-prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Dart or Pub question really, it's a Windows, MacOS, Linux etc. shell process control question.

The question is more suited to Stack Exchange Superuser https://superuser.com/ I believe. You could look over there for more detailed answer ... but ... assuming you are using the windows command prompt:

`start /B` starts a process in the background.

`tasklist` can be used to look up running process PIDs.

`taskkill /PID` kills a running process.

You can use `help <command>` or search for documentation.

I have not used these personally but it looks awkward as `start /B` does not give you the PID of the process it ran. Unix shells such as Bash have good facilities for running processes in the background. Windows Powershell may have better support also.

Comment: You know what, you are absolutely right.  Thank you very much for your informative answer.

Comment: I was not sure if there was a dart way to do it, but im sure that i could just push command line stuff through dart to execute the target goals